Issue with Stripe Promotion Code "First-time Order Only" Restriction and Guest Customers
I am using Stripe’s promotion code functionality and have created a code with the "first-time order only" restriction to incentivize new customers. The purpose of this restriction is to ensure that the promotion code can only be used by customers making their first purchase, preventing reuse on subsequent orders. However, when I test this setup, Stripe creates a guest customer using the credit card number as a unique identifier. Despite the "first-time order only" restriction, the promotion code is applied for each purchase with the same credit card, which allows for repeated discounts.
{
  "id": "promo_1ExampleABC123",
  "object": "promotion_code",
  "active": true,
  "code": "NEWCUSTOMER10",
  "coupon": {
    "id": "coupon_1ExampleXYZ456",
    "object": "coupon",
    "amount_off": null,
    "created": 1723034203,
    "currency": null,
    "duration": "forever",
    "duration_in_months": null,
    "livemode": false,
    "max_redemptions": null,
    "metadata": {},
    "name": "10% Off for New Customers",
    "percent_off": 10,
    "redeem_by": null,
    "times_redeemed": 0,
    "valid": true
  },
  "created": 1723034204,
  "customer": null,
  "expires_at": null,
  "livemode": false,
  "max_redemptions": null,
  "metadata": {},
  "restrictions": {
    "first_time_transaction": true,
    "minimum_amount": 10000,
    "minimum_amount_currency": "usd"
  },
  "times_redeemed": 0
}

I created a promotion code with the following configuration:
Code: NEWCUSTOMER10
Restriction: First-time order only
Coupon: 10% off for new customers

When applying this code during checkout, Stripe creates a guest customer with a unique identifier (the credit card number).
I expected the promotion code to be applied only on the customer’s first purchase. However, I observed that the discount is applied for multiple purchases with the same guest customer, indicating that the restriction might not be enforced properly in this scenario.

You would need to define a Customer, and specify its Id when creating the CheckoutSession. Then you can limit the first time order in the promotion code.
